# Keep all header elements in same line with alignments in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to keep all elements in same line in jquery mobile header,Print and Save button should align to right side, Title should be center and other elements should be left align,I tried this in different way using css but still did not success
[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uderox/Y4Py2/3/)

Html

```
<div data-role="page" id="runTicketDetailsPage" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
   <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
      <a href="" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
      <a href="" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-icon="back" id="rtDetailsBtn" >Back</a>
      <span id="rtOffline" data-inline="true" style="color: #F00E1A;">ON</span>
      <span id="rtOnline"  data-inline="true" style="color:#0C8227; ">OFF</span>
      <h3  data-inline="true" id="title1">Info</h3>
      <a href="#" data-bind='click: save' id="btnSave" data-inline="true" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right"
         data-icon="plus">Save</a>
      <a href="" data-inline="true" data-role="button" id="rtDetailsBtn" >Print</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shinde87sagar/Y4Py2/5/

I have used

```
data-role="controlgroup"
```

to individual button groups.

```
     <div data-role="page" id="runTicketDetailsPage" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
         <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-btn-left" data-mini="true">
           <a href="" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
           <a href="" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-icon="back" id="rtDetailsBtn" >Back</a>
        </div>
       <div class="center-wrapper">
         <span id="rtOffline" data-inline="true" style="color: #F00E1A;">ON</span>
          <span id="rtOnline"  data-inline="true" style="color:#0C8227; ">OFF</span>
          <h3  id="title1">Info</h3>
       </div>

      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-btn-right" data-mini="true">
       <a href="#" data-bind='click: save' id="btnSave" data-inline="true" data-role="button" 
     data-icon="plus">Save</a>
       <a href="" data-inline="true" data-role="button" id="rtDetailsBtn" >Print</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```